# unexpected T variable in PHP

Tags: php, xampp

I'm new to PHP and I need a bit of an assistance.
I'm pretty sure that this has probably been one of the most common problems and has an easy fix but I've been trying. and I'll be so stupid about it

Alright, so here's my problem:
every time I go to my localhost to try and open my PHP site It won't because I get this error every time.

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$db' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\exam\register.php on line 4"

here's my PHP code.

```
    <?php
    session_start()

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "authentication");

    if (isset($_POST['register_btn'])) {
        session_start();
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $emailaddress = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailaddress']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password2']);

        if ($password == $password2) {
            $password = md5($password);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users(username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$emailaddress', '$password')";
            mysql_query($db, $sql);
            $_SESSION['message'] = "You are now registered!";
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("location: home.php");
        }else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "The two passwords do not match";
        }   
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a semicolon (`;`) missing in the line before that, in `session_start()`. That is why the parser is not able to recognize the variable `$db` in the next line.

```
session_start(); // <-- this semicolon is needed

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "authentication");
```

But there are other problems in your code as well. You are mixing between **mysql_** and **mysqli_** extensions. To connect to database, you are using `mysqli_connect`; while to escape the strings, you are using `mysql_real_escape_string` and `mysql_query`. This will not work.

**Firstly,** please get rid of **mysql_*** extension. It has been deprecated in PHP 5 and **removed completely** in  PHP 7.

Now, your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) instead. You can either use **mysqli** or **PDO** for the same.

**Secondly,** please don't use `md5` to encrypt your passwords. It is old and found to be having issues. Use standard PHP functions [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Do Read: [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/401656/2469308)

**Thirdly,** you have called `session_start()` twice. Please get rid of the second `session_start()` function call.

Comment: wow so that's so stupid of me. thank you

Comment: @RioAblas there are other problems in your code. Please check the edited answer after couple of minutes.

Comment: ahhh yes, I just noticed the mysql part. thank you hehehe